# SwiftUI: Text views concatenation how to do this with ForEach loop or array of strings

Tags: swift, swiftui, text, concatenation

I need to concatenate `Text()` views in SwiftUI using `+` operator

I tried something like this

```
Text("\(feed.author?.firstName ?? "") \(feed.author?.lastName ?? "") ")
                    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Medium", size: 15))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)


                ForEach(feed.titleChunks, id: \.self) { chunk in
                    + Text("\(chunk)")
                    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Regular", size: 15))
                    .foregroundColor(Color("BodyText"))
                }
```

But it of course doesn't work. Is there a way to get array of string of unknown number of elements printed using Text so that it forms single text view in SwiftUI just like

`Text("1") + Text("2") + Text("3")` does?

Is there some solution to this problem. I tired static approach and it works but I do not know in advance how much Text() I have

```
Text("\(feed.author?.firstName ?? "") \(feed.author?.lastName ?? "") ")
                    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Medium", size: 15))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)

                + Text("\(feed.titleChunks[0])")
                .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Regular", size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(Color("BodyText"))
                + Text("\(feed.titleChunks[1])")
                .font(.custom("AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(Color("BodyText"))
```

Answer (score 29):

`ForEach` quite confusigly is not a loop but a `ViewBuilder`

What you need is `reduce`. The docs describe it as:

> Use the reduce(*:*:) method to produce a single value from the
>   elements of an entire sequence. For example, you can use this method
>   on an array of numbers to find their sum or product.

In `SwiftUI` context you could use it as follows:

```
let words = ["This", "is", "an", "example"]

var body: some View {
    words.reduce(Text(""), { $0 + Text($1) + Text(" ")} )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This saved me a lot of headaches...

Answer (score 3):

I found solution using method or another view and there assemble Text concatenation using  `var output : Text` variable

```
  var output = Text("")

        let author = Text("\(feed.author?.firstName ?? "") \(feed.author?.lastName ?? "") ")
                    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Medium", size: 15))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)

        output = output + author

        for chunk in feed.titleChunks {

            let chunkText : Text
            if chunk.first == "#" {
                chunkText = Text("\(chunk)")
                .font(.custom("AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(Color("BodyText"))
            } else {
                chunkText = Text("\(chunk)")
                .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Regular", size: 15))
                .foregroundColor(Color("BodyText"))
            }

            output = output + chunkText
        }

        return output
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Works well for me however can you explain to me why you cannot use modifiers on the text views such as background, padding etc? Thank you

Comment: `.background`, `.padding`, etc. all return a `View` instead of a `Text`, and a `View` can't be concatenated onto a `Text`.